# Как реализовать адаптивность такого стилизованного бутстраповского аккордеона

Tags: html, bootstrap

Дано - цветные блоки при разрешении 1200 px в три ряда
каждый из них кликабелен
при клике должен открываться скрытый блок
соответсвенно при данном разрешении блок открывается  под первым рядом, вторым и третьим
при разрешении 980px в ряду остается по два блока - рядов становятся четыре
и опять скрытый блок должен открываться при нажатии на первый и второй блок под первым рядом, на третий и четвертый блок - под вторым рядом  и тд
и наконец при  760px  - блоки выстраиваются в колонку по одному и скрытый блок должнен раскрываться под каждым из них

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тк у вас в тегах указан bootstrap, то просто класс блокам добавить надо `col-md-6 col-sm-12`, смотрите описание бутрстрепа раздел `grid`

Answer (score 0):

Судя по конкретике вопроса - советую использовать @media для всех "переходных" разрешений экрана и для каждого задать свой стиль.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]